# Does this statue outside a school in India depict a Hindu Brahmin begging in front of Virgin Mary?

Tags: india, christianity, hinduism

[This video](https://twitter.com/SwamiGeetika/status/1048039418370514944) was circulating on social media with the following caption:

> At the entrance of St. Mary's H. S., Manapparai, Tiruchy, Tamilnadu, a brahmin is depicted as begging in front of Virgin Mary. Should Co-existance and secularism mean denigrating Hindu belief system?

It shows two statues outside a school named "St. Mary's HR.SEC. School", one of them is the Virgin Mary and another one shows a shirtless man with long hair.

Does the statue really depict a man belonging to the [Brahmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmin) class of Hinduism?

Comment: Is Swami Geetika notable?  (Honestly asking.  I really don't know.)

Comment: @BenBarden Never heard of her till I found this tweet when browsing through a completely unrelated hashtag.

Comment: I think that this question as-is is not notable.  It needs to be a claim by someone significant and/or a claim believed by a *large* number of people.  "random video circulating on the internet" isn't really good enough.

Comment: @BenBarden Then [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/42039/46715) isn't notable too because it shows a random meme without even a source for it.

Comment: Looks like you're correct.  At Skeptics, notability is on a challenge system.  The rule kicks in if someone challenges (which I have now done).  Looks like no one challenged that one.

Comment: I don't think there's anything unusual in art depicting one god bowing to another. For a close and popular example, Santa kneeling at a manger. So if this is notable, why are you skeptical?

Comment: Looking into the comments, I find the whole thing disturbing... people are trying to whip up confrontation and xenophobia, with comments like "[Christian] diseases need to be eradicated from India". But on the whole, this is entirely opinion-based. The people making the video and tweet claim "This is how **we** see it". We have no idea of the intentions of the ones that made the display what it is supposed to be.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question and it can be objectively answered at least in theory.

Comment: @Avery We do not do theoretical — or more accurately put — speculative questions here.

Answer (score 6):

The statue does **not** depict a Brahmin begging in front of Mary. It depicts the story of [Our Lady of Good Health](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_Lady_of_Good_Health), a 16th century apparition of Mary to a shepherd boy, who would have been of a lower caste.

You may see a similar diorama on [the official website of Our Lady of Good Health](http://vailankanni.info/velankanni-shrine-miracles/) (scroll down).